# "Too many open files" exception while running mvn org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:run

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin, jetty-8

In one of my project , I have used Lift 2.5 M4 and Scala 2.10.0 .  In this project , I am using  Jetty 8.1.10.v20130312 .
But while running project through mvn jetty  , I am getting unexpected exception  .

I have configured jetty plugin in pom.xml in below way :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.10.v20130312</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>org.apache.cocoon.log4j.loglevel</name>
                        <value>WARN</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>9090</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>30000</maxIdleTime>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                </webApp>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I am getting below exception while running command :- mvn org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:run

2013-04-24 06:49:39.216:WARN:oeja.AnnotationParser:EXCEPTION 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ayush/scala-lift/knolgame/target/classes/com/knolgame/lib/TransactionStatus$$anonfun$find$1.class (Too many open files)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.FileResource.getInputStream(FileResource.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:747)

But When I am using jetty 6.1.25 , It works fine .

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.25</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>org.apache.cocoon.log4j.loglevel</name>
                        <value>WARN</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>9090</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>30000</maxIdleTime>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
                <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this ?  I have to use latest Lift , Scala and jetty version in my application .

Thanks in advance .

Regards,
Ayush

Answer (score 4):

"Too many open files" usually means that your java process is not allowed to open any more file descriptors. 
However if this happens at startup of jetty w/o any big amount of connections opened something weird is going on.

First of all you can check the configured soft limit of allowed open files (or filedescriptors) by executing: `$ ulimit -a` on your commandline.

Please paste the results to here if you need further access.

Then you can use tools like `lsof` to check what files your java process failing with the given exception above has opened at that time. `$ lsof -p <pid>` where pid is the processId of your java/jetty process should give you some hints.

If your soft limit is just too small try raising it by following one of the many tutorials found in the internet like: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/ (first result I found) to raise the limit to something appropriate. What value will fit your application mainly depends on the amount of concurrent open connections you'll serve.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I have checked my ulimit . It is already unlimited .

Comment: Then please use lsof as described above to check what files are opened by your jvm when this error occurs.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem upgrading from jetty 6 to 8.  It seems jetty 8 does *something* that opens lots of files (though it doesn't seem any slower).  I took the following two steps to resolve the issue: 1) remove the default webapps and contexts that come embedded as part of the jetty 8 install 2) up the soft files limit 4096 and the hard files limit to 10240

Comment: Thanks @Taylor, your suggestion worked for me as well!